# Spring batch, unable to write on oracle database

Tags: database, spring, oracle, spring-batch

this is my xml file configuration.

```
    <batch:job id="pdgRecallJob">
        <batch:step id="stepTmpRecall">
            <batch:tasklet>
                <batch:chunk reader="readFileRecall" processor="" writer="tmpRecallWriter" commit-interval="10000">
                </batch:chunk>
            </batch:tasklet>
        </batch:step>
    </batch:job>



    <bean id="tmpRecall" class="it.mef.pdg.batch.model.TmpRecall" scope="prototype" />


    <bean id="readFileRecall" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader">

        <property name="strict" value="false" />
        <property name="resource" value="classpath:/properties/RECALLPDG_*.txt"/>
        <property name="lineMapper">
        <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper">
          <property name="lineTokenizer">
            <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer">
                <property name="delimiter" value=";"/>
                <property name="names" value="appNomeFile, appCodFisc, appRata, appImporto, appIscrizione, appNumTitolo, 
                appProgQuota, appAnnoEmissione, appCodEnte, appEsitoMef, appStatoFile, appDpt, appPostazione, appNLotto, 
                appDLotto, appNomeFileOrigine" />
            </bean>
          </property>
          <property name="fieldSetMapper">   
              <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper">
                    <property name="prototypeBeanName" value="tmpRecall" />
              </bean>           
          </property>
        </bean>
        </property>

    </bean>


    <bean id="tmpRecallWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcBatchItemWriter">

        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="sql">
            <value>
            <![CDATA[
                INSERT INTO APP_TMP_RECALL(APP_NOME_FILE,APP_COD_FISC,APP_RATA,APP_IMPORTO,APP_ISCRIZIONE,APP_NUM_TITOLO,APP_PROGR_QUOTA,APP_ANNO_EMISSIONE,APP_COD_ENTE,APP_ESITO_MEF,APP_STATO_FILE,APP_DPT,APP_POSTAZIONE,APP_NLOTTO,APP_DLOTTO,APP_NOME_FILE_ORIGINE)
                VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
            ]]>
            </value>

        </property>

        <property name="itemPreparedStatementSetter">
            <bean class="it.mef.pdg.batch.items.TmpRecallPreparedStatementSetter" />
        </property>

    </bean>     

    <bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="${db.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${db.user}" />
        <property name="password" value="${db.pass}" />
    </bean>
```

Then my itemPreparedStatementSetter Class:

```
final class TmpRecallPreparedStatementSetter implements ItemPreparedStatementSetter<TmpRecall>{

public void setValues(TmpRecall tmp, PreparedStatement ps) throws SQLException {

    ps.setString(1, tmp.getAppNomeFile());
    ps.setString(2, tmp.getAppCodFisc());
    ps.setInt(3, tmp.getAppRata());
    ps.setDouble(4, tmp.getAppImporto());
    ps.setString(5, tmp.getAppIscrizione());
    ps.setInt(6, tmp.getAppNumTitolo());
    ps.setString(7, tmp.getAppProgQuota());
    ps.setInt(8, tmp.getAppAnnoEmissione());
    ps.setString(9, tmp.getAppCodEnte());
    ps.setString(10, tmp.getAppEsitoMef());
    ps.setString(11, tmp.getAppStatoFile());
    ps.setString(12, tmp.getAppDpt());
    ps.setInt(13, tmp.getAppPostazione());
    ps.setInt(14, tmp.getAppNLotto());
    ps.setDate(15, tmp.getAppDLotto());
    ps.setInt(16, tmp.getAppNLotto());


}
```

}

My batch seems to work then I have final status COMPLETED, but it doesn't write no record inside my table.

I'm using jdk 1.5, ojdbc5-11.2.0.3.jar.

Either is there something I'm missing in my xml conf or any bean is not ok?

I was thinking that might be even a mismatch in Date field in table.

Comment: You don't need to add `processor=""` if you don't have a processor. Do you have any errors in the logs? Are you sure you are using a transaction manager and that transactions are committed (probably this is what is missing if you don't have any error)?

Answer (score 0):

You don't currently have an item processor, which (I think) is needed to pass records from the reader to the writer. Since you are not doing any processing (that is, your reader produces the same type that your writer consumes), I think you could use a [PassThroughItemProcessor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/index.html?org/springframework/batch/item/support/PassThroughItemProcessor.html) here.

Comment: Just wanted to mention that an item processor is optional. It is not needed to pass records from reader to writer.

Comment: Thanks @MahmoudBenHassine - I thought it might be.